# "(null)" wants to use "google.com" to sign in

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am trying to use FirebaseUI to prompt a user for a login from an iOS share extension (as opposed to my main app). Everything is working fine, except when the user clicks "Sign in With Google" or "Sign in With Facebook", they get an alert that says: "(null)" wants to use "google.com" to Sign In:

[image: Screenshot]

This is only a problem in the share extension, not in the main app. How can I make the pop-up correctly display my app name in the share extension? I checked for differences between the .plist in the extension and the app, but could not find any obvious root cause there.

Code excerpt:

```
let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
authUI?.delegate = self
authUI?.shouldAutoUpgradeAnonymousUsers = true
let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
  FUIEmailAuth(),
  FUIGoogleAuth(),
  FUIFacebookAuth(),
]
authUI?.providers = providers
present(authUI!.authViewController(), animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The code included in your question looks correct however, it really sounds like a plist issue for the extension - did you check NSExtensionPrincipalClass?. Why are you using and iOS share extension instead of implementing this in the app?

Comment: I took a look at the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsextension/nsextensionprincipalclass). It says NSExtensionPrincipalClass is the name of the class that implements the extension's main view, not the user-facing name of my app. I want to display "Awesome App wants to use google.com to Sign In", not "ShareViewController wants to use google.com to Sign In".

Re: why, I want users to be able to view content in the app without logging in, but I want to force them to log in to share their content with the extension.

Comment: P.S. I also agree that this sounds like a plist issue, however I cannot seem to figure out the right key in the plist to fix it. You'd think it would either be CFBundleDisplayName or CFBundleName, but I tried changing those and it does not help.

I apologize for the slow response and appreciate you looking into it, Jay.

Comment: There's a bit more code surrounding the pre-built authentication and the code in your question works for me. I suspect the issue lies with other code, still possibly a plist issue  or something else. Can you include a more complete and brief example?  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hey! Were u able to resolve this. I'm stuck with something similar

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If you change info.plist Bundle name is invalid. You need change in buildSetting -> Product Name